# Python - Getting different result from the same function call

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy

I defined the function below to obtain variable importance from a model. However, every time i run this function, the returned dataframe is different. even the model_rsqr changes.

somehow the input dataframe 'x_train' gets updated upon the function call. I feel its associated with df being referred to inside the function.

```
df= pd.read_csv("filename")
x_train = df[['cola','colb']]
y_train = df.colc

def model_var_importance(m, df, y):
    """
    m : tree ensemble ,
    df : pandas dataframe with independent variables, 
    y : dependent variable.
    """     
    #set random seed.
    np.random.seed(42)
    
    # function to get rsquared
    def rsqred(y,yhat): 
        return 1 - ((y-yhat)**2).sum()/((y-y.mean())**2).sum()
    
    # get model r-squared
    model_rsqr = rsqred(y, m.predict(df.values))
    print(model_rsqr)
    output_dict = dict()
    
    # get column importance
    for col_name, col_values in df.items():
        df[col_name] = np.random.permutation(col_values)
        pred = m.predict(df.values)
        col_rsqr = rsqred(y,pred)
        col_imp = model_rsqr - col_rsqr
        output_dict[col_name] = col_imp
        df[col_name] = col_values
    
    return pd.DataFrame(list(output_dict.items()),columns=['var','importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending = False)

model_var_importance(model1, x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: You are computing something based on some inputs (that you modify: `df[col_name] = np.random.permutation(col_values)`) and randomness. Why would one expect the output to be consistent between runs?

Comment: @CristiFati I intend to modify it only inside the function. i thought the variable defined in the global environment (here `x_train`) would remain the same. no?

Comment: @CristiFati - even if i don't assign it to a column in df, x_train gets updated. Below is an example.

`def model_var_importance(m, df, y):`
    `model_rsqr = rsqred(y, m.predict(df.values))`
    `print(model_rsqr)`
    `output_dict = dict()`
    
    `for col_name, col_values in df.items():`
            `a = np.random.permutation(col_values)`
     `return`

model_var_importance(model1, x_train, y_train)
-0.1451713097021603
model_var_importance(model1, x_train, y_train)
0.018164239438710927

Comment: @CristiFati - Sorry for the previous comment. i couldn't place the code properly. I have put sample code at the link below.. - 
https://gist.github.com/oshanmodi/2b4cc3d08e2a29a800cb994b2f25bf99